# How to select a attribute in a list of list using jq

Tags: json, jq

**Example**

With this input:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "primaryRefs": [
                {
                   "name": "a",
                },
                {
                   "name": "b",
                   "weight": 20
                },
            ],
            "siblingRefs": [
               {
                   "name": "d",
                },
                {
                   "name": "e",
                   "weight": 90
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "siblingRefs": [
               {
                   "name": "d",
                },
                {
                   "name": "e",
                   "weight": 90
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I would like to find `weight` in `rules.primaryRefs` whose `name` is `b`

In this example, it should return `20`

I solve it by iterating every

```
{
    "name": xx,
    "weight": xx
}
```

unit in `primaryRefs`

My filter is

```
FILTER='.rules[].primaryRefs[] | select(.name == "b") | .weight’
```

It returns the right result, However it returns an error if `primaryRefs` doesn't exist

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:85): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

I would like to not error out or return null when `primaryRefs` or `b` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either explicitly [check for the existence of the field using `has`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#has):

```bash
.rules[] | select(has("primaryRefs"))
| .primaryRefs[] | select(.name == "b").weight
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qRj8so-CGJf)

Or use the [error suppression operator `?`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#error-suppression-optional-operator):

```bash
.rules[].primaryRefs[]? | select(.name == "b").weight
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0fDgb19EvrV)